# Express JWT Permissions: How to set a permission?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, permissions, jwt

I'm reading the documentation of [Express JWT Permissions](https://github.com/MichielDeMey/express-jwt-permissions) but don't understand how to save the current user's permission in the token. I only see how to check the permission that has already set.

Could anyone post an example for setting the permission? e.g. let's say that we just authenticated the user and we want to give him an admin permission.

Answer (score 3):

You should add "permissions" property to JWT payload as an array of all permissions user has:

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

public static authenticate(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const payload = {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Smith',
    username: 'john.smith',
    permissions: ['USER', 'ADMIN'],
  };
  const options = {
    expiresIn: Number(process.env.JWT_TTL),
  };
  const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, options);
  res.status(201).send({ token });
}
```

Later, when user will send request with authorization token you should use express-jwt-permission lib for checking if user has the right permissions :

```
const guard = require("express-jwt-permissions")();

// all user routes
this.routes.use('/api', guard.check('USER'));
// ...

// all admin routes
this.routes.use('/api/admin/', guard.check('ADMIN'));
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem with that lib. Setting the token values is not part of any jwt-permissions lib, they assume that you had setted the correct values when the middleware is executed.

This is an example of how to set values in a token

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
const router = Router();
router.get('/api/v1/token', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ someData: 'foobar' }, config.getJwtSecret());
    res.json({ token: token });
});
```

that code was extracted from my public [node seed project](https://github.com/dengue8830/node-seed), take a look.